# What is the convention for organising interfaces and their implementations in a Go project?

Tags: go, conventions

What is the convention for organising interfaces and their implementations in a Go project?

I am new to Go and creating a small project, I currently have this folder structure:

```
src/
    my-repo/
        solve/
            backtracksolve.go
            permutatesolve.go
            ...
            solver.go

... (some repositories and packages omitted for brevity) ...
```

`backtracksolve` and `permutatesolve` both implement the interface `solver` so it make sense to keep them in the same package as the interface and other implementations of that interface, coming from Java/C# this is a common convention for example, `java.util` contains interfaces such as `Set`, `Map`, `List`, while also having implementations such as `HashSet`, `HashMap` and `ArrayList`.

However in Go because they both implement a `func Solve()` and both in the `package solve` there is `redeclared exception`.

Is it the convention to create a sub directory for each implementation (below) or something completely different?

```
src/
    my-repo/
        solve/
            backtrack/
                backtracksolve.go
            permutation/
                permutatesolve.go

            solver.go
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to create two types `BacktrackSolver` and `PermuteSolver` that both have the method `Solve()`. That would help against the name clash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally define different types that implement your `Solver` interface and then define the `Solve` function on those types.

```
func (s *BackTrackSolver) Solve() { … }
func (s *PermutateSolver) Solve() { … }
```

Because the types have distinct names there is no name clash. 
You can try it out online in [the go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/39Mgo9rkSh).

About your package convention question: I think a good approach is to start with all code in a single package and only export the types and functions you actually want to expose to your callers. Then later when you your [code cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) drops you should start splitting out code into multiple packages.

Also have a look at the "Organizing Go code" article from the [go blog](https://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code), subsection "What to put into a package" (short read).